# Change height of element while resizing window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you can see in the picture, I have a problems with my container in my slideshow. The gap between content and slideshow gets bigger the smaller the window size gets, which is what I want to avoid.

[image: Picture]

On resizing the window width, the content container shall change the height automatically pixel for pixel. So it gives the website a nice flow and there is no big space between the slideshow and the content on different screen sizes.

I made a JSFiddle now: https://jsfiddle.net/joggal/fk3v7aau/2/

Hope it shows my problem: the container is absolute positioned but i want it to resize so the gap between the slideshow and the container with the rows isn't too big / small. I want the container to be directly below the slider.

I tried to fix it with `@media` in the CSS, but this isn't the best solution at all :(

I hope you can help me :D

Comment: links to jsfiddle must include the code in the question itself

Comment: thanks, just approved it :)

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: If you are using bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples

Comment: I tried your CSS-Code without the position property at all, deleted all the position:absolute; and position:fixed; lines in your CSS-Code, and it looks better, the reason is you dont need it for your design, supposing you are using bootstrap

Comment: hey, yes i tried to make it without the absolute position but the problem that the container is allways hiding the carousel then.. thats why i had to make it absolute, since i am making the container scrolling over the carousel.

and yes, im using bootstrap! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. First get the height of the slider in window resize function.
2. Then append it to the image.

   `$( window ).resize(function() {
       var SliderHeight = $('.slide').height();
       $( ".img" ).css('height',SliderHeight);
   });`